# Maximum number of lines/editing commands in a SED script?

Tags: sed

As we all know, `sed` can read commands from one or more script files (or from `stdin`<sup>1</sup>) via `-f`.
This comes in handy when we need to make changes based on a list of patterns (or line numbers) as we can process the lines and turn them into editing commands which we then pass to `sed`. Sometimes the list is huge though so my question is

Is there a limit to the number of lines/editing commands that can be used in a `sed` *script*<sup>2</sup> ?

---

<sup>1: not all implementations support that though...</sup>
<sup>2: where *script* is obtained from combining all the `-e script` and `-f script_file` options</sup>

Comment: My own testing using a `sed -f` file with 500,000 lines works fine.  Of what magnitude are you testing against ?

Comment: As far as I read on manuals, there is no limitations about the number of lines/editing commands in a `sed` script. Does it seem so to you?

Comment: Are we looking for limits in various implementations?

Comment: Just curious what kind of answers you're looking for ("sed 1.2 on whonix 4.5 goes up to 2 million")

Comment: @JeffSchaller - something like that or _no, there's no limit - except your RAM_

Answer (score 2):

A brief glance at the source code of GNU sed 4.2.2 reveals a lot of malloc calls, and no boiled-in size constants. So, *no, there's no limit - except your RAM*.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` on OpenBSD 6.1: RAM is the limit.

The specific things that could cause trouble (if you are persistent about it) are:

1. Excessive number of labels (in the order of an `int`, I believe).
2. Filling up the hold space with too much data (in the magnitude of `size_t`).
3. Too long input lines (input data or script, but handles lines up to `size_t` length).

The `sed` script itself is compiled into a linked list structure.