# How many expression can be added in one sed command?

Tags: sed

`sed -e 'expression1' -e 'expression2' inputfile` works well.

For my works I add many expression in a `sed` command inside a shell script. But, the expressions are divided into two different colors.

[image] 
How many expression can be added in one `sed` command so that `sed` can handle it?

Comment: There's no restriction according to POSIX standard. But you can face the argument list too long error, as it's the limit for arguments passing to execve()

Comment: The change in colour is most likely to do with the terminal application and not the length of the command line.

Comment: Really similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322433/117549

Comment: Which sed? Which editor?

Answer (score 6):

1. `sed` scripts entered on the command line (or embedded in a shell script) can be any length up to the maximum command-line length allowed by your shell - megabytes long with modern shells.

   Also it's **not** necessary to use `-e` multiple times if you want a `sed` script to do more than one thing.  You can separate multiple commands with either a newline or a semicolon.

   For example, instead of:

   ```
   sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/abc/def/'
   ```

   you can do:

   ```
   sed -e 's/foo/bar/; s/abc/def/'
   ```

   or:

   ```
   sed -e 's/foo/bar
           s/abc/def'
   ```

   As with sh, additional whitespace between statements is insignificant.  I've used a space after the `;` in the first example above and more spaces for indentation in the second example to improve readability.

   Note that some `sed` commands are terminated only by a newline, not by a `;`.  These are well-documented exceptions to the general rule that `;` is a sed command separator, along with newline.  For details, see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html (this documentation is suitable for all/most versions of `sed` - GNU's non-standard extensions are noted when mentioned).

   For example, if you want to add a few lines of text immediately after a specific string, the `a` (append) command is one of the `sed` commands that can only be terminated by a newline.

   ```
   /search-string-here/ a\
   text line 1 ; semicolons are just text\
   text line 2 ; and more text here\

   <more sed commands can go here>
   ```
2. `sed` scripts can be **any** length you want, as long as you put the `sed` script in a file and separate each `sed` command with either a `;` or a newline (or both).  Run them with, e.g.:

   ```
   sed -f scriptfilename ...
   ```

   You can write standalone `sed` scripts just as you can for other scripting languages.  They can even be made executable with `chmod +x` if you have `#!/bin/sed -f` as the first line.

   For example:

   ```
   #!/bin/sed -f

   s/foo/bar/
   s/abc/def/
   ```
3. `sed` is not just a simple "command", it's a scripting language - most people just use it in a pipeline for a few small and simple regexp substitutions, but `sed` is capable of a lot more than that.

   See `man sed` for more details.  GNU `sed` also comes with complete documentation in [Texinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) format.  Run `info sed` to read it (or `pinfo sed` if you have the `pinfo` viewer installed - it's far superior to `info`).  The same documentation is also available in a variety of formats at https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/.

Comment: The semicolon works in this particular case, it does work for _many_ `sed` commands - but that doesn't mean it can be used as a separator for _any_ `sed` commands  as some of them can only be followed by a newline.

Comment: it's more accurate to say that `;` is a command separator in sed **except** for some well-documented exceptions which all have good reasons for being exceptions.  e.g. `a` for append, `c` for change, and `i` for insert.  they insert, change, or append text until an (unescaped) newline.  A semicolon in the text that's being inserted/etc, is just part of the text.  Also commands that read or write from files or execute shell commands (because `;` is used by sh itself, and it's a valid character in filenames, quoted strings, etc).   All of those are terminated by newline and not a semicolon.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html

Answer (score 3):

Up to the max length of the command line. The limit for the length of a command line is not imposed by the shell, but by the operating system. This limit is usually in the range of hundred kilobytes. POSIX denotes this limit ARG_MAX and on POSIX conformant systems you can query it with

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX    # Get argument limit in bytes
```

Test with:

```
$ sed $(printf ' -e s/%s//g' $(seq 0001000000)) file
```

Comment: @issac In my system it is `2097152` that means greater than 2G. see edited question.

Comment: @alhelal No, that is character count, that is a little over 2 meg, not giga.